# Return a mapping in Truffle test

Tags: truffle, testing

How would you guys call a mapping from a test and get the values?

This is the mapping that I have on my contract:

```
mapping(address => uint[29]) balanceOf;
```

It´s a mapping to an array of integers which reflects the different slots in the balance of the user. So, I´m trying to call directly from the `myTest.js (truffle)` but return me an error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
  at Context.it (test/ovxet2.js:13:50)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

And I´m doing this action like below, using async/await:

```
    var balanceOf = await instance.balanceOf.call({from: [accounts[0]][0]});
    console.log(balanceOf);
```

And I´ve also tried call in another way to receive the whole array of integers:

```
var balanceOf = await instance.balanceOf.call({from: accounts[0]});
    console.log(balanceOf);
```

However, I have another tests written using promise chaining...and I´ve implemented the same ways in order to get those values but return me the same errors.

So, can truffle returns mappings? Or I have to create my own getter function in the contract (for testing purposes) and then call that function from the test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot return a mapping type. Among the several reasons: keys are never stored and cannot be retrieved. A mapping doesn't known if a key has data or not, and it should return the whole structure which is 2^256 addresses containing 32 bytes each.

If your contract has declared

```
mapping(address => uint[29]) public balanceOf;
```

The solidity compiler will create a getter with a single parameter that will accept an address.

```
var balance = await instance.balanceOf.call(account);
console.log(balance);
```

Comment: That step in the test doesn´t work....returns : TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined...I´ve tried call balanceOf using accounts[0] and also {from: accounts[0]}....

Comment: @Jorge Note that I've added the `public` qualifier to `balanceOf` declaration.

Comment: Ah ok,but I also tried that way. Return Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function. I´ve tried calling in different ways: call(accounts[0]),call(acounts[0][0]), call({from: accounts[0]}) and call({from: accounts[0][0]}).   And also, I´ve kept away accounts[0] in a var and tried all ways, but the same result...

Comment: @Jorge It does work for me, perhaps my example is different. Without more code I cannot test what is wrong with yours.

Comment: But I think it doesn´t depend on the code. If the declaration is the same...and the way how you call the variable across the test is the same...I don´t understand why you are doing the process OK.

Comment: This answer worked well for me, thank you very much.

Comment: It should only work for public mappings. The one specified in the question is private.

Comment: @Ebube In my answer it is noted that it should be declared as public.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, the getter can be also called directly without the `call` prefix:

```
var balance = await instance.balanceOf(account);
console.log(balance);
```